# ValueError: Variable weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I can run my tensorflow code using tf.Variable but tf.get_variable is much more efficient. The above error is produced by this code:

```
    w = tf.get_variable(name='weights',
                shape=filter_shape,
                initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.01))
    b = tf.get_variable(name='biases',
                        shape=filter_shape[-1],
                        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.))
```

and I can't understand the reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

`tf.get_variable` works with variable scope to enable variable sharing. Here is an explanation on [how to share variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html#sharing-variables).

Specifically, I tend to separate variable initialization with fetching variable using the following framework.

```
def initialize_variables(scope_name, shape):
'''initialize variables within variable scope_name.'''
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name, reuse=None) as scope:
        w = tf.get_variable("weight", shape, initializer = random_normal_initializer(0., 0.01)))
        b = tf.get_variable("biase", shape[-1], initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        scope.reuse_variables()

def fetch_variables(scope_name):
    '''fetch variables within variable scope_name'''
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name, reuse=True):
        w = tf.get_variable("weight")
        b = tf.get_variable("biase")
        return w, b
```

Note that `reuse=None` setting in the `initialize_variables` function will make `w` and `b` recreate based on given `initializer` setting. In `fetch_variables`, `reuse=True` setting enables variable sharing.

Comment: The code that I wrote is inside a scope. If I want to restore a model including these variables, do I need to construct these separate functions or just the fetch_variables function? Because in the example I am seeing there is a checkpoint restoration and no initialization.

Comment: I wrote this code without checkpoint restoration and I am getting the same error again. All the code is writen in this scope: with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'). It's weird because when I initialize global step like this: global_step = tf.get_variable(
    'global_step', [],
    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)          there is no error.

Comment: If you want to restore a model including variables then you only need to fetch_variables. If you run the initialize_variables, you'd end up overwrite the stored values of the variables

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me how exactly you are using variable sharing from the description you gave, I'd need to see the code to speculate what went wrong. (also I think you may be confusing the purpose of variable scope and the purpose of tf.Graph)